# Windows Azure SQL dynamic scale did not work

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

im trying to scale my Azure SQL DB with php. All the other sql statements works fine, but when im sending

`ALTER DATABASE db1_abcd_efgh MODIFY (EDITION = 'Web', MAXSIZE=5GB);`

i get an error like that

`User must be in the master database.`

My database URL is that

```
xaz25jze9d.database.windows.net
```

and the database is named linke that

```
db1_abcd_efgh

function skale_a_m(){
$host = "tcp:xaz25jze9d.database.windows.net,1433\sqlexpress";
$user = "db_user";
$pwd = "xxxxx?!";
$db = "master";  //I have tried out db1_abcd_efgh at this point
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server= $host ; Database = $db ", $user, $pwd);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (Exception $e) {

}
$string = 'use master; ALTER DATABASE db1_a_m MODIFY (EDITION =\'Web\', MAXSIZE=5GB)';
$stmt = $conn->query($string);
```

}

Now i have modified my function linke this

```
function skale_a_m() {
$serverName = "tcp:yq6ipq11b4.database.windows.net,1433";
$userName = 'db_user@yq6ipq11b4';
$userPassword = 'xxxxx?!';

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $userName, "PWD" => $userPassword, "MultipleActiveResultSets" => true);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if ($conn === false) {
    echo "Failed to connect...";
}

$string = "ALTER DATABASE master MODIFY (EDITION ='Web', MAXSIZE=5GB)";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $string);
```

}

Now i get no errors but the Db did not scale?

Comment: Are you actually logged into the master database?

Comment: @ColinMorelli - this is about connecting to the master db vs a created db - something very appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: i think im conneted to the master db i post my connection function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ALTER DATABASE (Windows Azure SQL Database)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff394109.aspx), the `ALTER DATABASE` statement has to be issued when connected to the `master` database.

With PDO, this can be achieved by a connection string such as:

```
"sqlsrv:server=tcp:{$server}.database.windows.net,1433; Database=master"
```

Sample code:

```
<?php
function scale_database($server, $username, $password, $database, $maxsize) {
    try {
        $conn = new PDO ("sqlsrv:server=tcp:{$server}.database.windows.net,1433; Database=master", $username, $password);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $conn->setAttribute(constant('PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY'), true);
        $conn->exec("ALTER DATABASE {$database} MODIFY (MAXSIZE={$maxsize}GB)");
        $conn = null;
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
        die(print_r($e));
    }
}

scale_database("yourserver", "youruser", "yourpassword", "yourdatabase", "5");
?>
```

Note: It's not necessary to set the edition; it will be set according to the max size.

To test the sample code, configure it with your details (server name, login, password and database to be scaled) and execute it with PHP configured with the [Microsoft Drivers 3.0 for PHP for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).

After that, refresh (Ctrl+F5) the Windows Azure Management Portal and you should see the new max size reflected on the Scale tab of the database.

You can also verify that it worked by using a tool to connect to the scaled database (not to the master database) and issuing this command:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT,DATABASEPROPERTYEX ('yourdatabase', 'MAXSIZEINBYTES'))/1024/1024/1024 AS 'MAXSIZE IN GB'
```

Comment: Im using the standard user of the sql server. I only have one user. I have tested use master but der is an other error. USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different Database.

Comment: See updated answer for instructions on how to connect to master database using PDO.

Comment: thanks but i get an error on executing the statement                             Error executing SQL statement.PDOException Object ( [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '('. [string:Exception:private] => [code:protected] => 42000 [file:protected] => C:\xampp\htdocs\dbOperations.php [line:protected] => 45 [trace:Exception:private] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\dbOperations.php [.......

Comment: The command is correct. You can verify that by executing it with SQL Server Management Studio when connected to the master database. There seems to be an issue with the parsing done by the database driver. I'll look into it.

Comment: I have tried with VS2012 Ultimate SQL Server-Object-Explorer. There i can see that im connected to the master and the statement is successfull, but no effect on the DB.

Comment: I've updated the answer so that the SQLSRV_ATTR_DIRECT_QUERY attribute is set to send the statement directly to the server without preparation by the driver.

Comment: ok now i get NO errors. Thanks. But no effect on DB. The stay on the Web 1GB

Comment: NOW it works!!!!!!! Refresh time is very bad on the interface. Very big thanks!!!!!

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the answer with a SELECT command you can issue when connected to the scaled database (not the master) to verify the current max size. Notice you may need to refresh the portal to see the updated value, but the SELECT statement will reflect it immediately. If it still not works verify you're using the correct database and that your subscription is allowed to scale up. Do it manually via the portal to verify.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34009/discussion-between-fernando-correia-and-king-luy)

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'use master; ALTER DATABASE db1_a_m MODIFY (EDITION =\'Web\', MAXSIZE=5GB)'
```

I'm pretty sure SQL Azure does not support switching Databases using the `USE` command.

Try connect directly to the master db in your connection, and remove the `USE Master` statement from the start of your query.

```
$host = "tcp:xaz25jze9d.database.windows.net,1433\sqlexpress";
```

That also looks wrong to me. You shouldn't have a named instance called SQLExpress at the end of your server connection afaik.